# Running SSH Command from Raspberry PI in PHP

Tags: php, linux, ssh

when executing this command in linux wheezy throug SSH, it works fine;

```
pi@raspberry /usr/bin $ ./send -u 2 -i 0546845 -f
```

But how can i put this in for example test.php page (from var/www/test.php) so i can run this in a webpage?

Tried several things, but need some help getting into the right direction.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`system` function](http://php.net/system).

```
string system ( string $command [, int &$return_var ] )
```

Comment: Sorry, don't get this. 

This works fine:

<?php echo '<pre>'; // Outputs all the result of shellcommand "ls", and returns // the last output line into $last_line. Stores the return value // of the shell command in $retval. $last_line = system('ls', $retval); // Printing additional info echo ' </pre> <hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line . ' <hr />Return value: ' . $retval; ?> 

How should i enter my code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to reply to an "answer".. hehe..

I think you can simply do this:

```
system('/usr/bin $ ./send -u 2 -i 0546845 -f');
```

add that to your php script.